# how to set upper limit of memory consumption of MongoDB on Windows7

Tags: mongodb, memory

I am using MongoDB on Windows7(not Linux) as a data storage of our application prototype, and I have a trouble that MongoDB uses too much memory.
MongoDB can set upper limit of memory consumption in linux.
But I could not find it on Windows7.
Please tell me how to set upper limit of memory consumption of MongoDB on Windows7.

Comment: how to set it up on Linux?

Comment: @SalvadorDali  You tell me if you find out? Next's on me, then.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg did not get your comment. What were you referring to?

Comment: @SalvadorDali the next [whateverYourPreferredDrinkIs] is one me if you find out how to functionally limit MongoDB's memory usage without (para-) virtualization under Linux...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg got it. The problem is that I do not know how to do this. OP claims that he knows, but most probably he put it just to show that he has done some research without doing the research :-).

Comment: @SalvadorDali Got that. We both know it's not possible. So the drink's on me when you find out *and* tell me...